# MakeHuman "MHX FK/IK switch" missing

Tags: makehuman

I'm working with Blender 2.69 and MakeHuman 1.0.2. I have a character in MakeHuman, using the MHX format. I have the required addons to import MHX files into Blender, but I have an issue.

I'm trying to make a walk and run cycle for my character, following a tutorial by Alimayo Arango. He says to switch both legs of the character to Inverse Kinematics using the "MHX FK/IK switch" section in the Properties panel.

My problem is that on my end, it doesn't show up. It's supposed to be under "Import/Export MHP", but it's not. Can anyone help me? Doing walk cycles with forward-kinematics is painful as hell.

Comment: Could be a Blender version discrepancy? Maybe the option was moved to a different part of the interface. What version was he using, and what version are you using?

Comment: @Mentalist: He was using Blender 2.74. I'm using 2.69 as I couldn't even get the plugins to work on 2.74. I might try again in 2.74 as a last resort.

Comment: MHX or MHX 2? MHX hasn't changed in ages, so it doesn't matter what Blender version you are using unless it's maybe 2.5 Do you have the rest of the makehuman control panel, or are you missing the whole thing? Do you want to upload your file so we can check it?

Comment: did you try to reinstall makehuman?

Answer (score 1):

I have Blender 2.79 and MHX2, for those figuring this out lately.
I did not access this through the properties menu.

I have found that option from the menu option below: View->Tool Shelf

OR

Pressing T.

After that, a panel will appear on the left.
Under the MHX2 Runtime you will see the submenu FK/IK Switch.